# Como selecionar um pedaço da string Java?

Tags: java, string

Eu tenho a `String x = "@646646&"`.

Gostaria de pegar tudo o que está entre `@` e `&` e jogar em outra `String`. Independente de o que está entre esses caracteres ser número ou não.

Como faço?

Comment: Use expressões regulares para selecionar apenas números, http://regexr.com/ aqui você consegue testar sua expressão regular, por exemplo para pegar apenas número digite `\d` e isso selecionará somente os números de sua String

Comment: Você quer pegar somente números ou tudo o que está entre `@` e `&`?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli isso todo que esta entre ´@´ e ´&´

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar os métodos `indexOf()` e `substring()` ambos da classe `String`:

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "@646646&";
        int indexArroba = x.indexOf("@");
        int indexEComercial = x.indexOf("&");
        String resultado = x.substring(indexArroba + 1, indexEComercial);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
}
```

Saída:

> `646646`

---

### Explicação

O método `indexOf()` retorna a posição da **primeira ocorrência encontrada** da `String` passada como parâmetro. Caso não encontra nenhuma ocorrência retorna `-1`.

O método `substring()` retorna um pedaço de uma `String`.

Seus parâmetros são:

- `int beginIndex` : index de onde você quer que comece esse "pedaço" de `String`
- `int endIndex` : index de até onde você quer que vá esse "pedaço" de `String`

---

[Aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) você encontra a documentação oficial da classe `String`.

Answer (score 6):

*Nota: A pergunta foi editada e com isso esta resposta acabou sendo invalidada. Entretanto, vou manter a resposta aqui porque ela ainda pode ser útil.*

Utilize `x.replaceAll("(?:[^0-9]+)", "")`, onde `x` é a sua `String`.

Veja aqui um exemplo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String x = "@646646&";
        String z = x.replaceAll("(?:[^0-9]+)", "");
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/n95sul)

Ao invés de `"(?:[^0-9]+)"`, você também poderia usar o `"(?:[^\\d]+)"` que é equivalente.

Comment: Onde você coloca a expressão regular, poderia ser alterado para `\d` para assim selecionar somente os número da `string`?

Comment: @R.Santos Sim, poderia. Coloquei um último parágrafo acerca dessa observação.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ele editou a pergunta. Ele quer pegar tudo o que está entre `@` e `&`, independente de ser número ou não.

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 1):

Ainda utilizando expressão regular você poderia pegar o agrupamento

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String x = "@646646&";

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("@(.+)&");
    //Ou se sempre fosse apenas numeros
    //Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("@(\\d+)&");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(x);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String resultado = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/aL7jeX)